# How can I limit the caption to my workbook only?

Tags: excel, caption

When using the command "Application.Caption = 'Test' I'm able to put e.g. the version number in the title bar of my excel.  Unfortunately is this version number displayed than in all my open workbooks.

Is there no option available which allow me to show this caption only in the workbook from which the macro is running?

Answer (score 0):

You can change a workbook caption using the following :

```
ActiveWorkbook.Windows(1).Caption = "test"
```

Just replace "ActiveWorkbook" to whatever workbook you want.
More informations [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.window.caption).